# Where can I find information on the anatomy or biology of seeds?

Tags: seeds

Where can I find information on the anatomy or biology of seeds?

For example if I want to know the anatomy (some sort of drawing) of a green bean where can I go to find such information?

Searching Google does little to nothing to describe this process, let alone provide a good picture or drawing. The images of Google do return some results, but they are posts that were made by people on Twitter or Pinterest. Even Google Scholar does not have a lot of research papers on such info.

Seems like the only option is to purchase Text books which cost upwards of $200 each.

Please help....

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to find [this](https://www.seedimages.com/SeedResources.aspx) on google, which seems to collect a very large amount of information on different aspects of seed biology. I don't know if it has every species/feature that you care about, but there is a lot of general information there (including images).

Note that it has an "unsafe" web address (I clicked through and my computer wasn't taken over yet).

See also [this](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/seed+anatomy), found by google.

See also [this](http://www.seedbiology.de/structure.asp), from a german academic source.

There are also an enormous number of technical reports like [this](https://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/CAT87208646/PDF) and [this](https://www.fs.usda.gov/nsl/Handbook%20on%20Seeds%20of%20Browse-Shrubs%20and%20Forbs.pdf) from the USDA.

Comment: Hi, I guess this is my point. That there are only images but no official "safe" sites for such information.

Comment: @wwjdm If you are asking for whether there is a perfect catalog of comparative anatomy for the features that interest you in all the plants that interest you, I guess that is probably a no. However, I don't think it is too hard to look at e.g. the german source that I link to for general info, or to google scholar search "seed comparative anatomy beans" or whatever. What is an "official" site? the "unsafe" one is run by Ohio State University. The German one is also academic, the USDA is the USDA. No fancy web design in any of these places, but they are pretty official.

Comment: Thanks the USDA one you sent is good.

Comment: @wwjdm If this answer [addressed your problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.